# tens of thousands meaning

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-meaning

In [this article](https://www.chemistryworld.com/feature/what-it-takes-to-make-a-new-element/1017677.article), I saw the phrase tens of thousands. Normally, I understand tens of thousands means some number between 10.000 to 90.000. But in this situation, I don't really understand it:

> Oganessian reported his discovery to Flerov on his return. At first his mentor appeared dismissive – the usual fate for a successful guerrilla. It was only when the president of the USSR Academy of Sciences visited Jinr that Flerov pointed to Oganessian and said ‘He produces transuranes in their tens of thousands.’ The president, realising what this meant, gave Oganessian a kiss on his cheek.

What does tens of thousands mean in this situation?

Please explain to me.

Thanks

Comment: It's pretty badly translated. Transuranes isn't even English.

Comment: *tens of thousands* has its regular meaning.  But I have no idea what the rest of the sentence means.

Comment: I think it's a bad typo. It should be transuranium.

Comment: "Yuri Tsolakovich Oganessian .... born 14 April 1933) is a Russian nuclear physicist of Armenian descent, who is considered the world's leading researcher in superheavy chemical elements. He led the discovery of these elements in the periodic table. He succeeded Georgy Flerov as director of the Flerov Laboratory of Nuclear Reactions at the Joint Institute for Nuclear Research in 1989 and is now its scientific leader. " (continued in next comment)

Comment: (cont)  "The chemical element oganesson (Og, atomic number 118) was named after him in 2016, making him the only currently living person with an element named after him. " Source:  (Wikipedia)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Oganessian].  " transuranes in their tens of thousands" must mean tens of thousands of transuranium nuclei -- an impressive amount of the harder to make far transuranics.

Comment: @Jim I think you can read the full article. I thought it would be the amount of transuranium element they can make.

Comment: @DJClayworth "Transuranes isn't even English."? Google it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a NARQ.

Comment: Whatever they are, he produces them in quantities of that order of magnitude (10,000 or more).

Comment: @Kris I did. https://dictzone.com/german-english-dictionary/transurane

Comment: I suspect that, in this context, it simply means "a whole bunch".

Comment: Sorry, Knumber10; there’s nothing special there.

If "tens of thousands" has a special meaning either the author or the translator - should anyone care which? - failed to explain it.

The obvious problem is your maths: “tens of thousands means some number between 10.000 to 90.000”… Sorry but that's simply not true, by - obviously - at least one order of magnitude.

In fact, tens of thousands is between 10.000 to 99.000.

If you think the difference between 90 and 99 doesn’t matter, why would you not be happy to hand me - or anyone else - that proportion of your income, please?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually in the article itself, and the meaning is just the ordinary one.
The fragment in the question of course begs the question whether *tens of thousands* refers to separate *elements* (in which case we would have a hyperbole, because there are not even a hundred transurane elements) or to the amount of transurane material that was produced.

The article says, in the paragraph before the one in the question (emphasis mine):

> When Flerov went on an expedition to Siberia, Oganessian seized his chance. Testing his theory, he fired argon-40 at lead-208 to make fermium-244, predicting it would shed four neutrons and create an isotope with a half-life of only 4ms. The new technique produced fermium-246, losing only two neutrons, with a half-life of 1.1s. **The resulting yield was 10,000 times greater than he imagined**.

So Oganessian managed to produce 10,000 times more fermium than other techniques.

All said, the phrasing is certainly non-scientific and imprecise. Since it is a reported quote, we cannot put all the blame on the author. The reported reaction to the quote indicates that its meaning was well understood at the time, though, even if the wording is somewhat imprecise.

Comment: And since the typical yield is a handful of atoms, 10,000 times greater than a handful of atoms is indeed tens of thousands of atoms.

Answer (score 0):

it means **a lot**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/A+LOT) or even a bazillion!

[image: 10's of thousands ... give or take]

> a lot or lots Informal  A large extent, amount, or number

Vague numbers like **tens of thousands**, *hundreds of thousands* and *tens of millions* are **not** scientific. They typically are examples of hyperbole. Vague, intentionally vague, sensational or exaggerations, they make a generalized statement about the extent, amount or numbers. [Word Counter Blog](https://wordcounter.net/blog/2016/09/21/102367_tens-of-thousands.html)

As in:

> There must be hundreds of thousands of bacteria living on that
>   decaying food!

No more like a gazillion!

Comment: It suggests an order of magnitude, which is sometimes enough even in science. It is poor science to provide more precision than you have the data to support.

Answer (score -1):

> Normally, I understand tens of thousands means some number between 10.000 to 90.000.

*10s of 1000s* can also include such quantities over 90.000 as 100.000, 110.000, 500.000, 1.100.000, and up--as long as they're divisible by 10.000.

As an analog, consider *1000s*. You can raise *1000s* of dollars, which can mean any quantity divisible by *1000*, even *$1.000.000.000.000*. Such a high number is probably not in mind when someone uses the phrase *1000s* but it is not excluded linguistically and it is also mathematically valid. The same parameters apply to *10s of 1000s* except that the quantity must be divisible by 10.000, if we stick with numbers with no remainders (i.e., even numbers).

Comment: Literally, that might be the case. In common usage, though, “tens of thousands” doesn’t have the sense of “multiples of 10 000”.